# How to store encode file data into database with django ORM which has TextField

Tags: python, java, django

i have a java api which store byets stream as encoded data but i don't find anything in django to do that here is Java code :`

```
    File f1=new File(publicKeyFile);
        File f2=new File(privateKeyFile);
        if(f1!=null || f2!=null)
        {
            keys=new Keys();
            keys.setPublicKeyFile(f1);
            keys.setPrivateKeyFile(f2);
        }
```

and here is how it store like that in db

```
ÂÊLñ¢êl¹ jóEyº_ÿäFþ2ß[o‡V?óI©è4ÔågôJþ¨{A   Ae`§GŽjÿ&ømnÏ'
```

Šž‘Üè÷g¥åÿ  |ß-ë©ƒ¨Æ%°m”(åè}þY[S

but i can't save this as in django. basically i want something like that which java code is doing  please help

Comment: Why not use a binary field?